# Does chown always require sudo?

Tags: chown

Why does an owner of a file in Ubuntu need to run sudo in order to execute chown.

Running it without sudo results in an "Operation not permitted" error messge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File permissions are stored in the parent directory. You have to have `w` (write) access **to the parent directory** in order to change permissions, rename or delete files.

```
ls -ld .
```

will show the directory permissions.

Comment: Very clear answer. Noted the `w` access.

Answer (score 4):

You only have to run sudo if you change the owner or the group to a group you don't belong to. You don't need sudo to change the group to a group you already belong to. Note that this is specified in the POSIX standard.